# Access input text field inside Bootstrap Modal using JQuery .find()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to access the text which is entered into the input box but it keeps returning an empty string

Can someone help resolve the issue?

```js
$('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
 
  var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
  var txt = $(this).find('input[id="txt"]').val();

  $(this).find('button[id="save"]').click(function() {
    alert(id);
    alert(txt);
   });
  
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="1">Edit</a>

<div class="modal" id="my_modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Click Save!</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="txt" class="control-label">Text:</label>
          <input id="txt" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="1000"/>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="modal-footer">
       <button id="save" type="save" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to access the input value on modal showing, when actually the value is empty. You should access the value inside the click handler function of the button.

**Please Note:** `this` differs based on the context on which they are executing, thus `modal` click and `button` click has their own `this`. In order to preserve the intended `this` (the modal) you can store that in a variable and use that afterwards.

```js
$('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) { 
  var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
  var that = $(this);
  $(this).find('button[id="save"]').click(function() {
    var txt = that.find('input[id="txt"]').val();
    alert(id);
    alert(txt);
   });
  
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="1">Edit</a>

<div class="modal" id="my_modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Click Save!</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="txt" class="control-label">Text:</label>
          <input id="txt" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="1000"/>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="modal-footer">
       <button id="save" type="save" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You were showing the value you had recovered before onClick. Retrieving the value within onClick will resolve

```js
$('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
 
  var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
  var txt = $(this).find('input[id="txt"]');

  $(this).find('button[id="save"]').click(function() {
    alert(id);
    alert(txt.val());
   });
  
});
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-id="1">Edit</a>
    <div class="modal" id="my_modal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Click Save!</h4>
          </div>

<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="txt" class="control-label">Text:</label>
    <input id="txt" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="1000"/>
  </div>
</div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="save" type="save" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```